# WPF Service Call to WCF Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, wcf

We have a WPF app that returns data from a WCF Service.

Intermittently the code below will throw a 'Cannot access as disposed object' error - usually after one update sequence has already been made successfully.

Even closing the service and starting a new one at each call doesn't help. Any ideas?

Thanks...

```
 Private Sub Reports_BalanceSheet_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Try
        Dim vUpdate As New UpdateDelegate(AddressOf Reports_BalanceSheet_UpdateDB_Delegate)
        Dim vName As String = ReportName

        vService = New Service1Client

        Dim vID As Integer = 0
        If NewRecord = True Then
            Dim vRows As Integer = vService.ReturnScalarInteger("SELECT COUNT(Form_ID) From Balance_Sheet_Templates", Current_HOA_ID)
            If vRows > 0 Then
                vID = NullInteger(vService.ReturnScalarInteger("SELECT MAX(Form_ID) FROM Balance_Sheet_Templates", Current_HOA_ID))
            End If
            vID += 1
            'Save the form name
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO Balance_Sheet_Templates(Form_ID, Category_Type, Category_ID,  Form_Name) VALUES ("
            strSQL += "'" & vID & "', "
            strSQL += "'1', "
            strSQL += "'1', "
            strSQL += "'" & vName & "')"
            If vService.InsertDataHOA(strSQL, "Reports_BalanceSheet_Page 2466 " & Current_HOA_Name, Current_HOA_ID) = False Then
                IsError = True
                Dim Error1() As Object = {"There was an error updating the record"}
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Error1})
                Exit Sub
            End If


        Else

            vID = FormID
            strSQL = "DELETE Balance_Sheet_Templates WHERE Form_ID = " & vID
            If vService.InsertDataHOA(strSQL, "Reports_BalanceSheet_Page 2455 " & Current_HOA_Name, Current_HOA_ID) = False Then
                IsError = True
                Dim Error1() As Object = {"There was an error updating the record"}
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Error1})
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If




        Dim Update1() As Object = {"Saving the report defaults... Please wait..."}
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Update1})
        For Each Row As DataRow In ReportDT.Rows
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO Balance_Sheet_Templates (Form_ID, Category_Type, Category_ID, Form_Name) VALUES ("
            strSQL += "'" & vID & "', "
            strSQL += "'1', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("ID") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & vName & "')"
            If vService.InsertDataHOA(strSQL, "Reports_BalanceSheet_Page 2417 " & Current_HOA_Name, Current_HOA_ID) = False Then
                IsError = True
                Dim Error1() As Object = {"There was an error updating the record"}
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Error1})
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next



        Dim Update2() As Object = {"Saving the revenue categories... Please wait..."}
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Update2})
        For Each Row As DataRow In RevenueDT.Rows
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO Balance_Sheet_Templates (Form_ID, Category_Type, Category_ID, Position, Key_String) VALUES ("
            strSQL += "'" & vID & "', "
            strSQL += "'3', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("ID") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("Position") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & SubmitText(Row("Name")) & "')"
            If vService.InsertDataHOA(strSQL, "Reports_BalanceSheet_Page 2434 " & Current_HOA_Name, Current_HOA_ID) = False Then
                IsError = True
                Dim Error1() As Object = {"There was an error updating the record"}
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Error1})
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next



        Dim Update3() As Object = {"Saving the revenue data... Please wait..."}
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Update3})
        For Each Row As DataRow In RevenueNomDT.Rows
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO Balance_Sheet_Templates (Form_ID, Category_Type, Category_ID, Position, Cat_Name_ID, Nom_Code, Nom_Name) VALUES ("
            strSQL += "'" & vID & "', "
            strSQL += "'4', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("ID") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("Position") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("CatID") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("NomCode") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & SubmitText(Row("NomName")) & "')"
            If vService.InsertDataHOA(strSQL, "Reports_BalanceSheet_Page 2453 " & Current_HOA_Name, Current_HOA_ID) = False Then
                IsError = True
                Dim Error1() As Object = {"There was an error updating the record"}
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Error1})
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next



        Dim Update4() As Object = {"Saving the expenses categories... Please wait..."}
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Update4})
        For Each Row As DataRow In ExpensesDT.Rows
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO Balance_Sheet_Templates (Form_ID, Category_Type, Category_ID, Position, Key_String) VALUES ("
            strSQL += "'" & vID & "', "
            strSQL += "'5', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("ID") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("Position") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & SubmitText(Row("Name")) & "')"
            If vService.InsertDataHOA(strSQL, "Reports_BalanceSheet_Page 2472 " & Current_HOA_Name, Current_HOA_ID) = False Then
                IsError = True
                Dim Error1() As Object = {"There was an error updating the record"}
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Error1})
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next



        Dim Update5() As Object = {"Saving the expenses data... Please wait..."}
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Update5})
        For Each Row As DataRow In ExpensesNomDT.Rows
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO Balance_Sheet_Templates (Form_ID, Category_Type, Category_ID, Position, Cat_Name_ID, Nom_Code, Nom_Name) VALUES ("
            strSQL += "'" & vID & "', "
            strSQL += "'6', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("ID") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("Position") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("CatID") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("NomCode") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & SubmitText(Row("NomName")) & "') "
            If vService.InsertDataHOA(strSQL, "Reports_BalanceSheet_Page 2491 " & Current_HOA_Name, Current_HOA_ID) = False Then
                IsError = True
                Dim Error1() As Object = {"There was an error updating the record"}
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Error1})
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next




        Dim Update6() As Object = {"Saving the assets categories... Please wait..."}
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Update6})
        For Each Row As DataRow In ResIncomeDT.Rows
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO Balance_Sheet_Templates (Form_ID, Category_Type, Category_ID, Position, Key_String) VALUES ("
            strSQL += "'" & vID & "', "
            strSQL += "'7', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("ID") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("Position") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & SubmitText(Row("Name")) & "')"
            If vService.InsertDataHOA(strSQL, "Reports_BalanceSheet_Page 2509 " & Current_HOA_Name, Current_HOA_ID) = False Then
                IsError = True
                Dim Error1() As Object = {"There was an error updating the record"}
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Error1})
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next




        Dim Update7() As Object = {"Saving the assets data... Please wait..."}
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Update7})
        For Each Row As DataRow In ResIncNomDT.Rows
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO Balance_Sheet_Templates (Form_ID, Category_Type, Category_ID, Position, Cat_Name_ID, Nom_Code, Nom_Name) VALUES ("
            strSQL += "'" & vID & "', "
            strSQL += "'8', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("ID") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("Position") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("CatID") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("NomCode") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("NomName") & "') "
            If vService.InsertDataHOA(strSQL, "Reports_BalanceSheet_Page 2529 " & Current_HOA_Name, Current_HOA_ID) = False Then
                IsError = True
                Dim Error1() As Object = {"There was an error updating the record"}
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Error1})
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next




        Dim Update8() As Object = {"Saving the liability categories... Please wait..."}
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Update8})
        For Each Row As DataRow In ResExpensesDT.Rows
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO Balance_Sheet_Templates (Form_ID, Category_Type, Category_ID, Position, Key_String) VALUES ("
            strSQL += "'" & vID & "', "
            strSQL += "'9', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("ID") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("Position") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & SubmitText(Row("Name")) & "')"
            If vService.InsertDataHOA(strSQL, "Reports_BalanceSheet_Page 2548 " & Current_HOA_Name, Current_HOA_ID) = False Then
                IsError = True
                Dim Error1() As Object = {"There was an error updating the record"}
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Error1})
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next




        Dim Update9() As Object = {"Saving the liability data... Please wait..."}
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Update9})
        For Each Row As DataRow In ResExpNomDT.Rows
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO Balance_Sheet_Templates (Form_ID, Category_Type, Category_ID, Position, Cat_Name_ID, Nom_Code, Nom_Name) VALUES ("
            strSQL += "'" & vID & "', "
            strSQL += "'10', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("ID") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("Position") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("CatID") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("NomCode") & "', "
            strSQL += "'" & Row("NomName") & "') "
            If vService.InsertDataHOA(strSQL, "Reports_BalanceSheet_Page 2566 " & Current_HOA_Name, Current_HOA_ID) = False Then
                IsError = True
                Dim Error1() As Object = {"There was an error updating the record"}
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(vUpdate, New Object() {Error1})
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next




    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex, False)
        IsError = True
    Finally
        If Not vService Is Nothing Then
            vService.Close()
            vService = Nothing
        End If
    End Try
End Sub



Private Sub Reports_BalanceSheet_WorkCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    Try
        If IsError = True Then
            AppBoxError("There was an error updating the record!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        PageStatusBarLoaded(Reports_BalanceSheet_Grid, "Template was successfully saved...")
        PageStatusBarRightChangeText(Reports_BalanceSheet_Grid, "Template updated...")
        Dim SaveUpdateButton As Button = Reports_BalanceSheet_Grid.FindName("BalanceSheet_SaveUpdateButton")
        If NewRecord = True Then
            SaveUpdateButton.IsEnabled = False
            SaveUpdateButton.Content = ReturnToolBarImageGrey("Record_Insert.png")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub



Private Sub Reports_BalanceSheet_UpdateDB_Delegate(ByVal x() As Object)
    Try
        PageStatusBarRightChangeText(Reports_BalanceSheet_Grid, x(0).ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The error returned

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
```

Object name: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsChannelFactory`1+HttpsRequestChannel[System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel]'.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfDisposedOrNotOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at HOA_Manager_Client_04.ServiceReference1.IService1.InsertDataHOA(String strSQL, String LineNo, String HOAID)
   at HOA_Manager_Client_04.ServiceReference1.Service1Client.InsertDataHOA(String strSQL, String LineNo, String HOAID)
   at HOA_Manager_Client_04.Reports_BalanceSheet_Page.Reports_BalanceSheet_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throughout the app vService is defined in each page

```
Private strSQL As String
Private vService As Service1Client
```

and is created as New when required. Something was clearly also using and closing this at the same time so I just created a brand new service

```
 Private Sub Reports_BalanceSheet_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Dim vService1 As New Service1Client
    Try
        Dim vUpdate As New UpdateDelegate(AddressOf Reports_BalanceSheet_UpdateDB_Delegate)
        Dim vName As String = ReportName

        ' vService = New Service1Client
```

and changed every update instance to that - and so far it seems to be working. Odd that this is the only place in the entire app it was throwing this error